# Ошибка при заходе на сайт 522 + проблемы с сервером

Tags: centos, vps

После перезагрузки сервера перестал работать сайт. Нельзя подключиться через FileZila, Putty и т.п.
При попытке захода на сайт выдает ошибку 522.

При запуске vps выдает ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ошибки при вводе команды systemctl:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если войти в систему штатными способами никак, то загружайтесь с LiveCD (нормальный VPS-хостинг должен предоставлять такую возможность) и через него читайте ошибки в системных логах

Comment: @andreymal главная проблема в том, что как то взаимодействовать с файлами не возможно(нельзя подключиться через FileZila, Putty и т.п.). По видимому максимум что доступно, это консоль.

Comment: Как я уже написал в первом комментарии, нормальный VPS-хостинг должен предоставлять возможность загрузиться с LiveCD. Если же такой возможности почему-то нет — меняйте хостинг на более адекватный

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под фразой «максимум что доступно, это консоль»? В неё можно залогиниться и выполнять команды?

Comment: ...впрочем, упавший systemd-logind намекает, что, вероятно, нельзя. Ну тогда опять — LiveCD

Comment: @andreymal в консоль через хостинг зайти можно. можно выполнять команды и они будут работать

Comment: Ну тогда вперёд читать логи и смотреть в них ошибки — `systemctl --failed` чтобы узнать список упавших служб, `journalctl -b -u имя` чтобы почитать логи конкретной службы и так далее по ситуации

Comment: @andreymal добавил ошибки при вводе команды systemctl. как я понимаю это серьезные ошибки

Comment: Ну вот значит `journalctl -b -u polkit.service` и так далее по аналогии изучать что происходит